# What information is OK to store in cookies?

Tags: cookies

When thinking about security and user experience, what information id OK, acceptable, or even a **good idea** to store in a cookie?

EDIT:

---

With the understanding that sensitive info, like user names, passwords, SSN, credit card numbers don't belong there, what **does**?

Comment: Perhaps it would help if you would describe a scenario you are designing and then elucidate the data you need to persist.

Comment: Nothing specific, I was just wondering more in general. Sort of best-practices for what information is particularly useful to put in cookies.

Comment: You might be interested in this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3206622/is-putting-data-in-cookies-secure

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Definitely not passwords! Or anything sensitive... remember that cookies are stored on people's computers so from your point of view (as a website developer), they're basically out in the wild, potentially accessible to anyone.

A common practice is to just store a session ID in a cookie, and store all other relevant information in a database (or file, or whatever) on the server, indexed by session ID.

Comment: Is there a good tutorial online that you can think of that shows how to accomplish your suggestion?

Comment: Is "cookies" the best way to store user profile information like interest, hobbies etc to avoid making unnecessary `GET` requests? Or is session ID the best way to do this?

Answer (score 16):

It's a lot easier to answer what's *not* acceptable to store in a cookie.  Anything that should remain secure shouldn't be stored.  That includes passwords, credit card numbers, social security numbers, etc.

I think it's *okay* to store a user's login name, since that information really isn't sensitive.  A user's preferences settings for your site should be okay as well.

Remember, cookies are just plain text files that someone (or some application) can open up and read *or write*, so you shouldn't trust information you receive from a cookie, either.  Sanitize it just like any other user input.

Comment: "You shouldn't trust information you receive from a cookie ... Sanitize it just like any other user input." You impressed me!

Answer (score 6):

One suggestion is that you **not** store any keys to your database in cookies.  i.e. email addresses, column ID's etc.  If so, you should encrypt the data.

Answer (score 5):

- User customization ID (a set of preferences stored in a db which you fetch on page load)
- No personal information

Answer (score 4):

Well other than sensitive and security related data there really is no limit to what you can't and can store but just remember that if that data is not persisted on the server side, it could be lost altogether and it should be assumed that if the user deletes cookies, it won't inconvenience him too much to restore his settings/configuration. There are no guidelines other than using good common sense here.

There are however limits to cookies. You should not exceed 19 cookies per domain and no cookie should be bigger than 4KB (4096 bytes) as per [IE limits](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306070):

> Each cookie begins with a name-value
>   pair. This pair is followed by zero or
>   by more attribute-value pairs that are
>   separated by semicolons. For one
>   domain name, each cookie is limited to
>   4,096 bytes. This total can exist as
>   one name-value pair of 4 kilobytes
>   (KB) or as up to 20 name-value pairs
>   that total 4 KB. If the computer does
>   not have sufficient space to store the
>   cookie, the cookie is discarded. It is
>   not truncated. Applications should use
>   as few cookies as possible and as
>   small a cookie as possible.
>   Additionally, applications should be
>   able to handle the loss of a cookie.
>
> If a Web application uses more than 19
>   custom cookies, ASP session state may
>   be lost. Internet Explorer 4.0 and
>   later versions allow a total of 20
>   cookies for each domain. Because
>   ASPSessionID is a cookie, if you use
>   20 or more custom cookies, the browser
>   is forced to discard the ASPSessionID
>   cookie and lose the session.

Comment: Link in answer is dead (*Sorry, page not found*).

Answer (score 3):

Don't store anything in a Cookie that will allow your site to be hacked or accessed without going through proper channels.  Usually, just a session ID or user ID is stored in a cookie, and often in a form intended to be opaque to anyone but the cookie consumer.

Answer (score 2):

I would avoid storing anything that, if altered, would compromise the functionality of the site.

So, storing something like a user id, shopping cart items' prices, password, user roles, etc. are problematic.  I keep this kind of thing in the user's session data on the server.

Storing a user's name or profile info (for display purposes only), customization preferences (colors, text, whatever) are fine.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong in saving sensitive information on a cookie, as long as that information is encrypted (the data itself is not clear text) and the cookie is a secure cookie (https). Actually it is much worst to have all of the sensitive data in one DB server that might be hacked and then you are facing a potentially much bigger security issue.