# Is javascript object with data of client save?

Tags: javascript, server-side

I instanciated an (javascript)object which should contain sensible data from our clients(read in via PHP from a database).

My question is now, if this data is save or should I let this run exclusively server-side?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Safely Storing sensitive data client side](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11760602/safely-storing-sensitive-data-client-side)

Comment: In my opinion, sensitive data should never be exposed on the client's HTML/JS files even if it's encoded. Of course you can encrypt your data or hash it and then it might be possible

Comment: Well, it all depends on where you actually need the information to be. It the client doesn't need it, it'd be silly to store it there. If if needs it, it'd be unavoidable.

Comment: The data should be editable by the user and later gets written to the database again. Since I'm just starting with Web development I'm sadly not that familiar with this stuff.